# Access Data Layer from Previous Page

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm using a Javascript data layer across a domain of mine and due to certain analytic requirements surrounding conversion tracking, when a lead is converted I need to look back at the page type (tracked in the data layer) of the previous/referring page. I'm gathering the previous page's url with `document.referrer` but because this isn't a function, I can't pass it my data layer call for the page type.

My current understanding of `document.referrer` as well as `history` is that I can't access any elements of the previous page without stepping back to that page in the browser with `history.go(-1)` which is not acceptable for my purpose. This has lead me to think I'll either need to use a Session or Cookie for tracking purposes or setup a 1x1 pixel iframe on each page that contains the previous page so I can access the element.

Is there another method I can use to access my data layer aside from redirection, an iframe, or a Session/Cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You indeed can't access the previous page. There are several methods to store data, either client or server side.

For server side you should check the environment you use, but I guess all have a basic 'Session' where you can store data. Also, you could always use a database as backing system if persistence is important.

If it is okay to keep the data on the client only, you could use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for example.

Comment: We're already using several databases for various tracking and marketing elements which is something I've considered but want to avoid for a number of reasons. The easiest method would be to piggy-back on one of the Sessions/Cookies that we set.

Comment: Okay. You have to keep in mind you can lose that data if the session times out or the server sessions gets recycled. Only use `Session` for data that may be lost or can be recovered.

Comment: Correct, there are options to be considered for each and depending on how we're tracking other odds and ends will determine which one, Session or Cookie, I will be able to piggyback on.